# Java equivalent to the C# array declaration of private static double[,][] _temp = null;

Tags: c#, java, arrays

I have this C# code:

```
private static double[,][] _temp = null;
```

I don't think I've ever used an array declaration with a comma in it before. I assume it's some variation of a jagged array. Can anyone confirm what the C# code does?  Also, does anyone know what its equivalent code in Java would be?

Comment: Re: equivalent in Java: Java doesn't have true multidimensional arrays in the C/C++/C# sense, so there's no direct equivalent. To translate it to Java you'd either have to make it jagged in all three dimensions, `double[][][]`, or else create a two-dimensional-array wrapper class to convert `[i,j]` to `[i*numCols+j]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that a 2 dimensional array?

```
private static double[][] temp = null;
```

EDIT:

Three dimensional:

```
private static double[][][] temp = null;
```

Comment: Could the phantom downvoter please explain why this is an incorrect answer?

Comment: Maybe you were downvoted before the edit?  It's also not exactly a 3D array, but it's close enough in most situations.

Comment: It's a functionally different meaning.  You can generally use it the same, but functionally it's different.  Technically you've got a jagged array of jagged array of arrays of doubles.  It's more like a `Matrix<Double>[]`

Comment: Gotcha... Sometimes I wonder why I bother answering questions on SO when I'm just going to lose reputation even for a correct answer.

Comment: Don't feel bad. Java may not have an exact equivalent and that's good to know. However, that doesn't get me any closer to converting this code. You're the first person that  offered code to allow me to do it, so I'm accepting yours as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

That would be an array of fixed-sized two dimensional arrays. <strike>fixed-size (rather than jagged) two dimensional array of arrays</strike>.

Comment: Hmm, I'd phrase it as "an array of two dimensional arrays", but maybe that's me.

Comment: @Kirk - To be honest, I'm not entirely sure that the way I've written it is correct.

Comment: Out of curiosity wouldn't it be equivalent to `double[,,]`?

Comment: It's an array of two dimensional arrays.  Start from the outside and work your way in.

Comment: @Danny, functionally equivalent (though syntactically quite different), except for the jagged/fixed-size nuance.

Answer (score 1):

The `[,]` is a rectangular array (not jagged).  (And with one comma, 2D.) The point would be to gain a performance benemfit over the usual Java array of arrays (which can be jagged).  You can locate an element with a bit of arithmetic and dereferencing one pointer rather than dereferencing two pointers and less arithmetic.  Not sure it would help for small arrays--might hurt--but with large ones the `[,]` probably gives much better cache performance.  Would also help a lot on a machine with an array processor.  (Some people still use FORTRAN because it handles arrays real well on machines with array processors.)  C# tends to add special stuff to get little--or big--bonuses like that.  Java tries to stay simple even when it costs something.

Then the other `[]` gives you a possibly jagged array of non-jagged arrays, just like in Java.

Comment: Interesting. I will be dealing with a huge amount of data. Is it possible to create a class in Java that would have the performance benefits you describe or is that something that can only be done at a lower level?

Comment: @adam0101: Hmmm. I'm somewhat at the limit of my knowledge here. If you have a vector processor, or a Graphics Processing Unit, you might want to do some research from that angle. Otherwise, in Java, given a W by H array, use a single dimensional array and calculate the index of (x,y) as `int i = (W * y) + x`.  (Dimensions that are powers of 2 will speed your calculations.) Experiment a bit. One other thing: the Virtual Machines are getting so good at on-the-fly optimizing it may not matter what you do; they may do all this work for you and do it better. Also: pamper your Garbage Collector.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [site](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Introducing_C_Sharp_Arrays#Declaring_a_Multidimensional_Array) a comma inside [] is like declaring a double dimensional array in C#. So in your case, it'd be an array of double dimensional arrays.